MySQL event not executing
I've tried to set up an event that will copy the state of table Daily_Prices into a Price_History table.
The event code is as follows:
CREATE EVENT CopyTodayPrices
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
STARTS '2024-08-13 20:25:00'
ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE
ENABLE
DO
BEGIN
    -- Ignore if prices are old (if the unique index throws an error)
    INSERT IGNORE INTO Prices_History (`Kreditorennr`, `Bar Code`, `Tagespreis`, `Preis vom`)
    SELECT `Kreditorennr`, `Bar Code`, `Tagespreis`, `Preis vom`
    FROM Daily_Prices;
END;

It doesn't insert any rows into the table Price_History.
I've tried to run the code between BEGIN and END manually as a query in DBeaver after the event was suposed to run and it successfully inserted all the rows.
Event scheduler works:
> SHOW PROCESSLIST;

|Id |User           |Host                |db    |Command|Time |State                      |Info                                                                          |
|---|---------------|--------------------|------|-------|-----|---------------------------|------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|5  |event_scheduler|localhost           |      |Daemon |1,597|Waiting for next activation|                                                                              |

And the event also seems to be scheduled:
SHOW EVENTS;

|Db    |Name           |Definer|Time zone|Type     |Execute at|Interval value|Interval field|Starts             |Ends|Status |Originator|character_set_client|collation_connection|Database Collation|
|------|---------------|-------|---------|---------|----------|--------------|--------------|-------------------|----|-------|----------|--------------------|--------------------|------------------|
|nocodb|CopyTodayPrices|root@% |SYSTEM   |RECURRING|          |1             |DAY           |2024-08-13 20:25:00|    |ENABLED|1         |utf8mb4             |utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci  |utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci|


You have Price_History in comment and Prices_History in query. With plural priceS.

That was my problem... Thank you.
